# Assertion Error while compiling Solidity code in Ethereum

Tags: compilation, ethereum, solidity

H:\Ethereum\Kickstarter\ethereum>node compile.js
H:\Ethereum\Kickstarter\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var Module;if(!Module)Module=(typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:null)||{};var moduleOverrides={};for(var key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof require==="function"&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE){if(!Module["print"])Module["print"]=function print(x){process["stdout"].write(x+"\n")};if(!Module["printErr"])Module["printErr"]=function printErr(x){process["stderr"].write(x+"\n")};var nodeFS=require("fs");var nodePath=require("path");Module["read"]=function read(filename,binary){filename=nodePath"normalize";var ret=nodeFS"readFileSync";if(!ret

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback specified.
    at wrapCallback (H:\Ethereum\Kickstarter\node_modules\solc\wrapper.js:16:5)
    at runWithReadCallback (H:\Ethereum\Kickstarter\node_modules\solc\wrapper.js:37:42)
    at compileStandard (H:\Ethereum\Kickstarter\node_modules\solc\wrapper.js:78:14)
    at Object.compileStandardWrapper (H:\Ethereum\Kickstarter\node_modules\solc\wrapper.js:85:14)
    at Object. (H:\Ethereum\Kickstarter\ethereum\compile.js:19:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)

Answer (score 2):

The following would get the latest stable version of the Solidity Compiler:

```
    npm install --save solc
```

For me the issue was with this version. I downgraded *solc* using the following command to an older version (after removing the currently installed version).

```
    npm install --save solc@0.4.17
```

This resolved the issue. Furthermore, I changed the first line of my *smart contract* in my *contracts* directory to:

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
```

Comment: Hi Divyanshu, thanks for your comments. Though I have installed the solc latest stable version, I am using the 0.4.17 version by mentioning it on the top of the contract. Any more thoughts on this. Please comment if you will get any other solution on this.

Comment: The latest stable version is causing issues, try downgrading the _solc_ version. Hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

run following command, as suggested by Divyanshu

npm install --save solc@0.4.17

and verify that the first line of your contract is

pragma solidity ^0.4.17;